How to rig towing multiple carts / trailers

What is the best way to rig these carts to the pins to allow for realistic towing animation without keyframing every rotation and movement? There should be 2 Z-axis rotation points, one is the yellow pin, and the other is a pin directly behind first cart. Robot already has keyframes that moves it around the scene, and the yellow pin is parented to it. I need the carts to be pulled around wide turns while connected to the pins in a realistic way. I don't care if the cart caster wheels are realistic as well, just need to animate an example of what turning with these carts looks like. Haven't been able to find anything close to this made in the last 5 years.

If you can, I would have the robot run along a curve instead. That way you can use an old curve deform modifier solution. Is that possible?
